# How do I create a HTML <table> in Cakephp and have it populate correctly?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application that works great.  I am retrieving data from a table and it produces a big long single column list down the page view.  I want to change that so it populates a 3 column HTML Table.  Anybody know how to do this?

This is the line I need to output display in 3 columns....

```
echo $this->Form->input('Activity', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

Right now it just makes a big long single column that runs down the length of the page with multiple checkboxes.

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('Activity', array('row' => 3));

Comment: This did not work.....I tried row, cols, column, rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... I hope it will help you.

echo $this->Form->input('Activity', array('cols' => 3));

Comment: Nope...did not work.  I tried row, rows, cols, column

Comment: Is there a way to do this in CSS?  Leave my statement alone and let it list everything in one long column and then use CSS somehow to put it in 3 columns?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

echo $this->Form->input('Activity', array('cols' => 3, 'type'=>'textarea'));

OR

echo $this->Form->textarea(
    'textarea',
    array('rows' => '5', 'cols' => '5')
);

Comment: Still no go....it acts like it has no idea what "cols" or "rows" mean.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Still no good.....this would never work anyway...it has to be a Form->input statement too.

Comment: There are alternative that performs the same action.

Comment: I've used these two statement many times and achieved the desired result. Maybe i'm not getting your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Activity', array(
    'type'=>'checkbox', 
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
    'format' => array('before', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'after', 'error') 
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to split your data into 3 parts. You could do this by counting the data and dividing by 3 (pseudo-code, untested):

```
$splitArray = [];
$colHeaders = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
foreach($checkboxes as $index => $checkbox) {
  array_push($splitArray[floor(count($checkboxes)/3)], $checkbox);
}
```

The HTML helper can help you build tables:

```
<table>
  <?= $this->Html->tableHeaders($colHeaders) ?>
  <?= $this->Html->tableCells($splitArray)) ?>
</table>
```